# Parsing data in javascript with selenium

Tags: javascript, json, selenium, nightwatch.js

I am trying to read data from a json file in javascript. I can read succesfully read from it. When passing in the data in the code it throws errors. 
Any help will be appriciated.

My code is as follows :

```
 module.exports = {
'@tags': ['TC2'],
"LAUNCHURL" : function (browser) {
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('C:/NightWatch_Automation/credentials.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {

if (err) throw err; // we'll not consider error handling for now
var mydata = JSON.parse(data);

var url_get = mydata.credentials[0]['url'] //Passing data works here 

    browser
    //opens salesforce and checks title to match 'Login | Salesforce'
    .url(url_get)
    .waitForElementVisible('//body', 1000)
    //.assert.title('Login | Salesforce')
    });

},

"Login": function(browser) {
 var fs = require('fs');
 fs.readFile('C:/NightWatch_Automation/credentials.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
 if (err) throw err; // we'll not consider error handling for now
 var mydata = JSON.parse(data);

 var email = mydata.credentials[0]['email']

  browser
    .useXpath()
    .click("//a[contains(text(),'Sign In')]")
    .waitForElementVisible('//body',1000)
    .setValue("//input[@aria-label='Enter email address']", email )//Passing data does NOT work here 
    .click("//button[@type='button']")
    .waitForElementVisible("//input[@id='password']")
    .setValue("//input[@id='password']","password12345")
    .click("//button[@type='button']")
     });

 }
};
```

My json file is as follows

`{ "credentials": [  {"url": "https://www.walmart.com", "search": "bandaids", "email" : "test@yahoo.com", "password" : "password12345"}] }`

*Further info*
When the values are hard coded, the script works. As soon as a attempt to pass in data in breaks the code and wont complete. Using nightwatch as a test tool.

Comment: launchurl and login do asynchronous things, but themselves are not asynchronous (there are no callbacks, no promises, no async functions). That means you fire and forget both functions. Your functions will run in parallel and will not get any error output

Answer (score 0):

The paths are different which might be the problem:

LAUNCHURL: `fs.readFile('C:/NightWatch_Automation/credentials.json'`

Login: `fs.readFile('C:/Users/NightWatch_Automation/credentials.json'`

Comment: Sorry, I edited that for the sake of the code example. They match in the actual code. I will edit that now.

Comment: Allright, I'll keep on looking what the problem might be